# How to add background music to avi files

Tags: audio, youtube, avi

I noticed that on youtube some people add background music to their videos. What program do they use to do this? Is it something that youtube provides?

Comment: `avi` tag is inappropriate. Not all youtube videos are AVI, and AVI isn't the only format that supports sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can now use http://www.youtube.com/editor, or simply use video editors for your OS (like Windows Movie Maker or iMovie).